# Generating Sample datetime between specified time

Tags: r

How to sample time between a specified time from 08:00:00 to 17:00:00, Right now the below code generates random date&time between 24 hours.

Is there a way to specify the time range in my function!

```
dtime <- function(N, st="2012-01-01 08:00:00", et="2012-01-02 19:00:00") {
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  rt <- st + ev
}

a <- dtime(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

"st" and "et" are just integers representing the number of seconds from the start.  Therefore you can pass these numbers to the `sample` function:

```
dtime <- function(N, st="2012-01-01 08:00:00", et="2012-01-02 19:00:00") {
  st <- as.POSIXct(st)  
  et <- as.POSIXct(et)
  ev <- sample(st:et, N)  #select from the range st to et
  as.POSIXct(ev, origin="1970-01-01")
}

dtime(30)
```

This does provide a random sampling only down to the nearest second.

```
[1] "2012-01-01 14:50:44 EST" "2012-01-01 04:17:56 EST" "2012-01-01 11:35:01 EST" "2012-01-01 11:15:01 EST"
[5] "2012-01-01 03:38:29 EST" "2012-01-01 08:27:55 EST" "2012-01-01 12:45:26 EST" "2011-12-31 19:51:47 EST"
[9] "2012-01-01 15:28:56 EST" "2012-01-01 02:54:52 EST" "2012-01-01 13:41:38 EST" ….
```

Comment: Hi @DaveT still i get date times beyond 8:00 and 19:00

Comment: yes @DaveT i tried it still some outputs ```[19] "2012-01-01 16:13:20 IST" "2012-01-01 23:20:16 IST" "2012-01-01 19:25:38 IST"
[22] "2012-01-01 08:25:31 IST" "2012-01-01 12:03:26 IST" "2012-01-01 23:53:59 IST"```

Comment: @prog, The times from your comment are within the time window of 1/1 to 1/2.  Double check the default times in the function.